# Merge cells of excel sheet from the data from database PHPExcel class

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Im trying to format the excel sheet with PHPExcel class. The scenario is i fetch data from the database and i want to merge the header cells according to the count of items.

database output and the cell merging i need is shown in the image 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGzUy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet's `mergeCells()` method: e.g.

```
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:B3');`
```

as shown in the examples such as [05featuredemo.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php#L132) and described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#mergeunmerge-cells)

But your code will have to keep track of the item headers that you're adding,an work out the range of cells that need merging

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i know that it can be done by using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:B3');`. But my problem is the headers are coming from database, so have to merge the cells dynamically rather than hard coding as 'A1:B3'..

Comment: Well you'll need to keep track of the columns that your'e putting each item heading into, and build that range definition from the columns you use for the first and last item in each group.... it's just a string to build.... but as I don't know what your code looks like, I can't really suggest anything more